# Авторизация на сайте

Tags: php, авторизация, mysql

Добрый день!

Мне нужно сделать авторизацию на сайте. Электронная почта + пароль, а также восстановление пароля, как правильно сделать авторизацию по e-mail (просто всегда нахожу только пол логину) и восстановление пароля.

Comment: Что значит авторизация по мылу? 1) то есть за место логина мыло так? 2) или требуется просто активация по мылу? 3) И уточните что вы хотите теорию или готовый код?

Comment: за место логина мыло

Comment: Форма регистрации состоит из следующих полей:
- Имя
- Фамилия
- email
- Пароль
- Подтверждение пароля.
Форма авторизации:
- Email
- Пароль
После успешной авторизации в шапке приложения должна быть приветствие (Hello, имя!)
и ссылка на выход из системы.
Страница “Мой аккаунт” выводит данные текущего пользователя, которые он указал
при регистрации. Должна быть возможность редактирования этих данных. Данная страница доступна только после
авторизации.
Основные задачи для выполнения:
- Форма регистрации
- Форма авторизации
- “Мой аккаунт”
Дополнительные:
- Восстановление пароля
- Загрузка аватара

Comment: Ясно, скажите что вам из этого непонятно?
Или вам требуется готовое решение?

Comment: мне требуется по возможности готовое решение, а непонятно как авторизацию делать по мылу, вывод своей страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> непонятно как авторизацию делать по мылу

точно также как по логину, только используйте не люгин, а email (все просто), и изменить проверку ввода данных в поле логин, для проверки мыла

```
function email($input) 
{
    $check = '/^[a-z0-9!#$%&*+-=?^_`{|}~]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&*+-=?^_`{|}~]+)*';
    $check.= '@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+([a-z]{2,3}';
    $check.= '|info|aero|name)$/ix';

    if (preg_match($check, $input))
    {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

> вывод своей страницы

как я понимаю речь идет о профиле, так?
тут вообще все просто, просто выводите данные из БД о пользователе, создаете ссылку для формы редактирования

для того чтобы организовать закрытую зону, воспользуйтесь сессиями и куками

> мне требуется по возможности готовое решение

думаю что за вас тут писать, никто, нечего не будет, тут немного другое нежели сайт фрилансеров.
идеи вам дали, будут какие то конкретные вопросы по реализации авторизации, мы всегда ответим

> тогда вопрос есть по восстановлению пароля? как сделать?

1. Создаем форму куда пользователь будет вписывать свой логин для востановления
2. Проверяем есть ли пользователь в базе
3. Если юзер есть в базе, то генерируем новый пароль.
4. Для безопасности я советую вам хранить пароли в зашифрованом виде. Поэтому перегоняем в md5 хеш.
5. Переписываем пороль в базу уже хэшированым
6. Шлём пороль на это мыло

   //шлём пороль на это мыло

   mail($mail, "Запрос на востонавление пороля", "Здравствуйте $login ваш новый пороль : $string");

Comment: тогда вопрос есть по восстановлению пароля? как сделать?

Comment: ответил выше